# pulling from a repository that requires authentication with a Python script

Tags: authentication, mercurial

I am using the hgapi module to run mercurial commands through a Python script.  I have the following code:

```
example_repo = hgapi.Repo('C:/Users/JohnDoe/workspace/example')
example_repo.pull()
```

Because I am pull from a repository that requires http authentication, it throws an exception:

hgapi.hgapi.HgException: Error running hg --cwd C:/Users/JohnDoe/workspace/example pull:
" + tErr: abort: http authorization required

Out: 
Exit: 255

Is this a limitation of the hgapi?  Is there a different method I can use to pull from a repository that requires authentication through a Python script?